# Group of elevators in a building

Tags: single-word-requests, collective-nouns

If we assume a large building with multiple elevators, what would be the name of a group of elevators?

Consider a group all those in close vicinity to each other, in the same hall but not necessary with the same amount of locations (stories). If a wide building is considered, it's perfectly possible to have for example 2 elevators at the North side and 2 elevators at the South side of the building. North and South would be considered their own group (if the distance between them is large enough).

Example usage:

> We're walking towards the Northern group of elevators.
>
> Two out of three elevators from the Southern group of elevators broke down.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A 'bank' of elevators is what I've seen in literature and heard spoken. So far as I know, elevators were not hunted 500 years ago or thereabouts, so you're not likely to find a classical term of venery. That opens the door for making your own term up, as appropriate and understandable ("a Stonehenge of lifts") in context, but if you're going for immediately recognizable, 'a bank of elevators' is in common use. See the [Wikipedia elevator entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator) for multiple instances, but a web search will reveal the prevalence of the term.

Comment: Yep, when we'd visit my dad where he worked in the  Empire State Building (1960's thru 1980's) we always had to ask 'which *bank* of elevators',  because they didn't all go to the same floors.

Comment: Yeah, "bank" is what I'd normally say.  Although I may have used "herd of elevators" once or twice.